# MongoDB Invalid Email and Password when saving user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

there is a problem I've been stuck with where when I try to create a new user I get the following error:

`ValidationError: User validation failed: 0.password: Path`0.password`is required., 0.email: Path`0.email`is required.`

now the endpoint used to work and Im thinking its something to do with the db itself but I cant for the life of me figure out what to do.

I am passing the valid data of course.

here is the model and payload:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import BaseSchema from '../utils/schema';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const userSchema = BaseSchema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    firstName:String,
    lastName:String
});
userSchema.virtual('name').get(function(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        this.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

and the payload to save (this was debugged right before the save) is:

```
{ email: 'somevalidemail@gmail.com',
  password:
   '$2b$10$oQN7i5AKYDyPLp.DefeRjuyh9Z7JLayPjTO4I3B6NvytM0vq2YnVG',
  firstName: 'Cool',
  lastName: 'Cat' }
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the problem.
had two:

1. Had an issue with BaseSchema (not listed here) where the fields did not pass correctly.
2. Had then an error:`E11000 duplicate key error index: chat-app1.users.$0.email_1 dup key: { : null }'`
   which led me to believe that it was an indexing problem. dumped the collection indexes

After fixing the base and clearing the indexes it all worked again

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loosing the "this" context.

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My password hashing worked, But I took your code just to make sure. it did not make a difference.